# c# Saving richTextBox Data to txt file

Tags: c#

I have a rich text box in c# with data in it and I need it saved in a txt document on the desktop.

I have tried this:

```
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        using(File.Create(path));
        txtLogBox.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

AI get an error that I can't save to the desktop. ANy help would be great.

Comment: What is the error exactly?  Are you running the application as administrator?  Its probably a permission issue.

Comment: I have also tried this and still get an error relating to privelages

Comment: Your question shouldnt be "saving rich text to a txt file", it should be "privilege error when writing to desktop".  Have you tried writing your file somewhere else?

Comment: Always, *always*, post the EXACT error message, please!

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms ? RichTextBox is totally different !

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to create a file that has the name of an existing directory. You need to append a path separator ([Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and a file name.

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
txtLogBox.SaveFile(path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "example.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

(Your `using` statement is unnecessary here because `RichTextBox.SaveFile(string)` handles this for you.)

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to work out why i still get this error though http://gyazo.com/b04477e92aded7a617c0ca2864ec145e

Comment: Sorry, my example had a stray parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry just one more thing. http://gyazo.com/170045d846d13e4d08271b889de4df1a How do I get rid of these formatting like text?

Comment: That's because we passed `RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText` (which is for actual RTF with formatting) instead of `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText`. If you want to preserve formatting, keep `RichText` but change the extension to `.rtf`.

Comment: Do you know `Path.Combine(...)` ?

Comment: `Path.Combine` would probably work fine, but don't forget that it returns its second argument (ignoring its first argument) if it's an absolute path. Be sure to read [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) carefully to understand how it works exactly.